# Trigger to Update Parent Column Based on Child Table Count

Tags: mysql

I Have a Table called :

```
Home

HomeID, HomeAddress, Capacity.
```

another called :

```
Children

ChildID, HomeID,Childname.
```

Is there a way in which i can auto update each Home table capacity column with the amount of children it has linked as a foreign key in the Children table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use 2 triggers for this to achieve.

1. after update on children
2. after delete on children

**Example 1**: ***After UPDATE***:

```
delimiter //

drop trigger if exists au_on_children //

create trigger au_on_children after update on children 
for each row
begin
  declare old_totalCapacity int not null default 0;
  declare new_totalCapacity int not null default 0;

  select 
    case when homeID = OLD.homeID 
              then sum( OLD.homeID ) 
         else sum( homeID ) 
     end 
    into old_totalCapacity ,
    case when homeID = NEW.homeID 
              then sum( NEW.homeID ) 
         else sum( homeID )
     end 
    into new_totalCapacity 
    from children;

  update home 
     set capacity =  
         case when homeID = OLD.homeID 
                   then old_totalCapacity  
              else capacity 
         end ,
         case when homeID = NEW.homeID 
                   then new_totalCapacity 
              else capacity 
         end ;
end;
//

delimiter ;
```

**Example 1**: ***After DELETE***:

```
delimiter //

drop trigger if exists ad_on_children //

create trigger ad_on_children after delete on children 
for each row
begin
  declare totalCapacity int not null default 0;

  select sum( homeID ) 
    into totalCapacity 
    from children 
   where homeID = OLD.homeID;

  update home 
     set capacity = totalCapacity 
   where homeId = OLD.homeID;
end;
//

delimiter ;
```