# How to update value of foreign key automatically

Tags: mysql

I have two table in a database. First one is

```
CREATE TABLE persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(30),
Address varchar(200),
City varchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
)
```

and the second one is

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
P_Id int,
PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (P_Id) REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
)
```

My question is there any way to update value of  FOREIGN KEY (P_Id) automatically in Orders table once primary key (P_Id) in Persons table get updated.
Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger to Update Parent Column Based on Child Table Count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035922/trigger-to-update-parent-column-based-on-child-table-count)

Comment: You really should not be updating primary keys.  Although you can use a cascading update, I think it is better to use an auto-incremented synthetic key.

Answer (score 1):

your second table should be

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
P_Id int,
PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (P_Id) REFERENCES Persons(P_Id),
ON UPDATE CASCADE
 )
```

This means that "ON UPDATE CASCADE" will do the same thing when id of the parent is updated.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned can be easily achieved by Using After Update Trigger on the Table **persons**.
Please do..

> Create Trigger trgUpdatePersonsPIDinOrders On dbo.persons After Update
>   AS Begin    Declare @OP_ID Int,@NP_ID Int    Select @OP_ID =
>   Deleted.P_ID From Deleted   Select @NP_ID = Inserted.P_ID From
>   Inserted   If @OP_ID <> @NP_ID   Then 
>       Update DBO.Orders Set P_ID = @NP_ID Where P_ID = @OP_ID End

May It will Help You 
Thanks